# How to fetch connection string from web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am calling a function of ClassA of Project A from ClassB of Project B but in this case i am getting connection string null from my web.config file.
Main issue may be i am calling from another project. so how to solve this.

I googled but no luck. give some suggestion for try.

Comment: If you have both project in single solution you can access that but some other error may be.

Comment: Can you show us your code how you call the connectionstring from the class where its null ? From there we may see what the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see you have two projects in same solution.
`Project A`
and 
`project B`

Your connection string is declared in `projectA` and you want to access this `connectionstring` from `projectB` 
there are two possibilities.

1. Better if you declare `<connectionStrings>` for `projectB` its a simple
   or
2. You need to create one static variable  which will return a connection string  in `projectA`

`public static string DBConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];`
            }

```
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get DB Connection string from Config File. Contact Administrator" + ce);
        }
    }
```